# Issues in indexing or querying

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, bigdata

every one I m a beginner with Big Data and trying to index and search the data. I have a problem
1)- While indexing program runs very smoothly but while Searching It always shows one or zero hit per query.

Like this:-

Skipped write.lock

Added: D:\Studies\Universities-Punjab University-\Notes\Final Year Project\Appache Lucene\Result 3\file.txt

Added: D:\Studies\Universities-Punjab University-\Notes\Final Year Project\Appache Lucene\Result 3\lab 1.txt

2 Documents Added.

Enter the Search Query (q=quit):

Waleed

Found 1 hits.

1. D:\Studies\Universities-Punjab University-\Notes\Final Year Project\Appache Lucene\Result 3\file.txt score=0.0390625

Enter the Search Query (q=quit):

Wlaeed

Found 0 hits.

Enter the Search Query (q=quit):

Ahmad

Found 1 hits.

1. D:\Studies\Universities-Punjab University-\Notes\Final Year Project\Appache Lucene\Result 3\file.txt score=0.0390625

Enter the Search Query (q=quit):

train

Found 1 hits.

1. D:\Studies\Universities-Punjab University-\Notes\Final Year Project\Appache Lucene\Result 3\lab 1.txt score=0.17900687

Enter the Search Query (q=quit):

q

Code for Indexing:-

```
    Reader fr = null;
    try {
        Document doc = new Document();

        fr = new FileReader(f);
        doc.add(new StringField("path", f.getPath(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new StringField("filename", f.getName(),Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("contents", fr));

        writer.addDocument(doc);
        enhanceList(f, helper);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could Not Add: " + f);
    } finally {
        fr.close();
    }
```

Code for Searching/Querying:-

```
void searching() throws IOException {
    String s = "";
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    IndexReader reader = DirectoryReader.open(FSDirectory.open(new File(directory)));
    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

    while (!s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter the Search Query (q=quit):");
            s = br.readLine();
            if (s.equalsIgnoreCase("q")) {
                break;
            }

            Query q = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_44, "contents", analyzer).parse(s);

            ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(q, 1000).scoreDocs;

            System.out.println("Found " + hits.length + " hits.");
            for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                int docId = hits[i].doc;
                Document d = searcher.doc(docId);
                System.out.println((i + 1) + ". " + d.get("path") + " score=" + hits[i].score);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error Searching " + s + " : " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Please any body help me out in finding out the solution..

Comment: The full function for your indexing code might be helpful in tracking down the problem. Right now, we don't know what the writer variable is, or what enhanceList does.

Comment: Writer is of simple IndexWriter type like

    Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File(directory));

  
IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_44, analyzer);
  
config.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
  
  
writer = new IndexWriter(dir, config);

and enhanceList is an auxiliary function which keeps track which files are indexed and which are not

Comment: Are you ever committing/closing the writer?